# ubuntu 15.10 (automatic logout killing every job)

Tags: unity, gnome, 15.10, logout

I recently upgraded from 14.04 to 15.10.

The system randomly logs out, killing every job I have running.

Is there a solution for this?
How/where can I best look for the reason for this (which log files?)

Thanks,
António